# Which dll i should import to use RoleProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-roles

I want my role provider class inherit from  RoleProvider. But which dll i must add dont know. I coulnt find anything about this issue except RoleProvider namespace has been changed in framework 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll
```